# Testing against multiple versions of jquery using jasmine and grunt

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit, gruntjs

I've written jasmine tests for a jquery plugin which I would like to automatically test against each version of jquery I claim to support. I've set up the tests to run for a single version of jquery using [grunt-jasmine-runner](https://github.com/jasmine-contrib/grunt-jasmine-runner), but how can I run the jasmine task several times, once for each version of jquery? And is it possible with qunit too?

Answer (score 3):

First I'd recommend you update to [Grunt v0.4](http://gruntjs.com/upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4) and switch to the (much improved) [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) module.

Once you've done that it should be trivial to configure multiple Jasmine targets that test your code using different versions of jQuery. You can reuse `options` blocks across all your test targets to reduce duplication. Something like (in `Gruntfile.js`):

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jasmine: {
        // Run the same tests everywhere.
        options: {
            specs: 'path/to/your/specs.js'
        },

        // Test against jQuery 1.6.x
        jQuery_16: {
            src: 'path/to/your/plugin.js',
            options: {
                vendor: 'path/to/jquery-1.6.2.js'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can duplicate the jQuery_## block as many times  as you need, changing the vendor path each time to point to a different version of jQuery. Note that you must repeat the 'src' definition each time.